# Removing block of text from csv file in Linux

Tags: linux, csv

I have a CSV file with lines similar to:

```
PerformanceData|712899|713|12|5.53|VERIFIED_TRADE N CoverDistribution SecurityTransfer (BondUKTI  / //-MO/W////.%)|5708|124.9
```

In column 6, I have a block enclosed in `( )` which I need to remove from each line of CSV. That is the only place where parenthesis will appear.

There is no pattern for what appears within `( )` but it will always enclosed in `( )`.

Expected output is:

```
PerformanceData|712899|713|12|5.53|VERIFIED_TRADE N CoverDistribution SecurityTransfer|5708|124.9
```

I am a newbie to Linux, can somebody help me to get the Linux command for this?

Comment: Is this the only place where parenthesis can occur?

Comment: @Panki Yes, that's the only place parenthesis will appear

Comment: @ParagMande Can you try below script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write script many way with full optimized, try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo  $line | cut -d "(" -f1 |xargs echo -n>> new.csv
  echo  $line | cut -d ")" -f2  >> new.csv
done < input.cvs
```

Comment: What is "my" in this script? Do I have replace it with something else?

Comment: @ParagMande I updated answer where `new.csv` contain expected data.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me!!

Comment: If It's helpful to you then swipe up-vote :) @ParagMande

Comment: I tried, but I get the following message:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: You may want to quote the expansion of `$line` when you use it with `echo`, and also make sure that `xpg_echo` is not set (would interpret backspaces as if `echo -e` was used). Also, you would need to remove `new.csv` before running the loop unless you simply use `>new.csv` after the loop instead of two separate `>>new.csv` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you just want to remove any parenthesis and the space before it, and assuming that the contents of the parentheses never contain a newline character, you could use

```
$ sed 's/ ([^)]*)//' file
PerformanceData|712899|713|12|5.53|VERIFIED_TRADE N CoverDistribution SecurityTransfer|5708|124.9
```

The expression  `([^)]*)` would match a space followed by `(`, followed by any number of characters that are not `)`, followed by a `)`.  This would be removed from the data.  Add `g` (as in `s/ ([^)]*)//g`) if you expect to have more than a single parenthesis on a line.

If you need to allow for any amount of whitespace before and after the parenthesis, then use `s/[[:blank:]]*([^)]*)[[:blank:]]*//`.   Each `[[:blank:]]*` would match any number of space or tab characters.

Comment: Somehow this did not worked for me. I may not doing it right! Thanks for answering @Kusalananda.